# Starting service with an initial value

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am trying to get a reminder/alarm  Service` working in my note/todo app.  I am able to set a reminder for a particular item and the alarm triggers and displays a notification successfully.

My problem is how can my `Service` know which note/todo item set that particular reminder.  I'd like for the user to be able to click on the notificaiton in the status bar and have the item which trigger it come up.  But I have no way of passing that information to the `Service` as they don't accept `Bundles` from the `PendingIntent`.

I currently set the alarm with the following:

```
private void createAlarm() {
     Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mReminderCal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

I just need a way to send along the `_id` of the item in my database so my Service can launch the item with that same `_id` when the notification is clicked.

I hope my question isn't too confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put all your need into Intent data? Something like this:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdatesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ID, "foo");
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Then on receiving end you do

```
    String id = getIntent().getStringExtra(ID);
```

Comment: But does this work for a `Service`?  Notice I'm using `PendingIntent.getService()`.  When I try to call `getIntent()` from `onCreate()` in my Service its undefined :(

Comment: oh snap, @Droidln.net!! you got me thinkin...First I tried it with an an `Activity`, the reminder/notification were working but it was coming up with a blank `Activity`.  THEN I tried it with a `BroadcastReceiver` and I think I got it working the way I want!  Thanks a ton for gettin me thinkin outside the `Service` method.

Comment: Definitely BroadcastReceiver, no need for blank Activities ever :) Glad to help